# How do I loop ROBLOX audio at a specific point?

Tags: loops, audio, lua, roblox

Here's my local script placed into the starter gui. I need the sound to loop after 62 seconds.

```
game.Workspace.Sound.Play()

local sound = Instance.new("Sound", game.Workspace)

sound.SoundId = "rbxassetid://145294677"

sound.TimePosition = 0

sound:Play()

wait(62)

sound:Stop()
sound:Play()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sound:Play()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Sound/Play) will reset the position to 0 or the last set value

```
local sound = Instance.new("Sound", game.Workspace)
sound.SoundId = "rbxassetid://145294677"
while true do
    sound:Play()
    wait(62)
end
```